# appcfg.cmd java version; 1.7 installed; 1.6 in path; tells me it needs 1.6 ti yokiad

Tags: google-app-engine

I try to use this command to deploy my application to
appspot.google.com:

`c:\a\appeng\bin\appcfg.cmd --use_java7 update c:\a\u3e`

Generates the error messsage.

`C:\a>c:\a\appeng\bin\appcfg.cmd --use_java7 update c:\a\u3e`

`Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.`

I tried setting the path to use the Java 1.6 SDK we downloaded
but that did not help or change any thing.

The web resources talk about what version of Java is used
by the application once it appears on Google's servers; I
did not see anything about the Java version for the upload
process including developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading and developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Command_Line_Arguments as well as searching this site specifically and checking google.

Can I deploy
an application from the computer in my house without 
deinstalling the Java 1.7 I use for other purposes?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking at this question.  I resolved the problem.  It was not related to Google Application Development
Server.  It was a difficult-to-resolve path problem to the directory where the Java executables were kept.